# Create a list of list with flexible input (Python)

Tags: python

I currently have a function that creates a list of lists like below using 3 nested for-loops.

```
[[1,1,1] , [1,1,2] , .... , [3,3,3]]
```

However, the problem is I can't use this function if someone wants the list of list to be something like

```
[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1] , ..... , [9,9,9,9,9,9,9]]
```

which has more numbers (from 1 - 9) and more elements (7 of 1's instead of 4).

Here's my current code:

```
def listofList():
    temp = []
    for i in range(1,4):
        for j in range(1,4):
            for k in range(1,4):
                temp.append([i,j,k])
    return temp
```

Can someone provide me with a better solution? I want my function `listofList()` to be flexible where it could receive an input for both the size of the list of list and the elements inside the list.

Comment: Don't delete your questions if you've received answers. Instead credit the answerer by voting on, and accepting their answers. Continue this behaviour and you will be banned.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
def listofList(subLen, totalLen):
    final = [[item for i in range(subLen)] for item in range(1, totalLen+1)]
    return final
```

---

```
>>> listofList(9, 9)
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8], [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]]
>>> listofList(9, 2)
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
>>> listofList(2, 9)
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 6], [7, 7], [8, 8], [9, 9]]
>>>
```